# Cannot cast bytearray to chararray in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a data as follows:

```
(000001, mfp=621|mdus=4.0|mduc=5.0|mas=1|mpc=4.0|mfn=1|country=ABC)
(00002, address=1000+mity|mus=1|name=kailtig+bksyt|mas=1|mpc=4.977552|country=ABC)
```

The fields are identifier and set of attributes.

I am trying to populate all the attributes in the data and do some operations on them.

So, I prepared my script as follows:

```
A = load 'myData.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (ID, ATTRIBUTES);
B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(ATTRIBUTES, '\\|')) ;
C = foreach B generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));
Dump C;

()
( mfp=621)
(mdus=4.0)
(mduc=5.0)
(mas=1)
(mpc=4.0)
(mfn=1)
(country=ABC))
( address=1000+mity)
(mus=1)
(name=kailtig+bksyt)
(mpc=4.977552)
```

Upto this point, it is working all right. But, the problem starts here.

When I try to do some operations on these attributes, for example replace 'm' by 'market'

```
D = foreach C generate REPLACE($0,'m','market');
```

gives me an error as follows:

```
 Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.REPLACE as 
 multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

When I try to cast the bytearray to chararray

```
D = foreach C generate (chararray)$0;
```

gives me error as:

```
 ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1052:
 <line 4, column 24> Cannot cast bytearray to chararray
```

But, the following link http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#cast says that piglatin supports cast from bytearray to chararray.

How can I solve this problem. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is 100% necessary for you to use byte arrays, but if it isn't you can use:

```
A = LOAD 'myData.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id, attrs) ; 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(attrs, '|')) AS attr:chararray ;
-- Now that the data is loaded as chararrays REPLACE will work 
C = FOREACH B GENERATE REPLACE(attr,'m','market') AS attrchanged ;
```

So that when attrs is split and flattened it will additionally be converted to a chararray. In general, you probably want to declare the type ahead of time with the schema.

The schema and output from each step are as follows:

```
A: {id: bytearray,attrs: bytearray}
((000001, mfp=621|mdus=4.0|mduc=5.0|mas=1|mpc=4.0|mfn=1|country=ABC))
((00002, address=1000+mity|mus=1|name=kailtig+bksyt|mas=1|mpc=4.977552|country=ABC))
B: {attr: chararray}
( mfp=621)
(mdus=4.0)
(mduc=5.0)
(mas=1)
(mpc=4.0)
(mfn=1)
(country=ABC))
( address=1000+mity)
(mus=1)
(name=kailtig+bksyt)
(mas=1)
(mpc=4.977552)
(country=ABC))
C: {attrchanged: chararray}
( marketfp=621)
(marketdus=4.0)
(marketduc=5.0)
(marketas=1)
(marketpc=4.0)
(marketfn=1)
(country=ABC))
( address=1000+marketity)
(marketus=1)
(namarkete=kailtig+bksyt)
(marketas=1)
(marketpc=4.977552)
(country=ABC))
```

Comment: I tried that, but using this approach populates only the following attributes by the second statement ----

()

( address=1000+mity)

Comment: I've added the schema and output for each step in my answer. Where exactly is the issue?

Comment: It works!!!! I think i overlooked the script. I tried to include tobag() function as well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

To the original question:

Since the input rows had different number of elements

```
(000001, mfp=621|mdus=4.0|mduc=5.0|mas=1|mpc=4.0|mfn=1|country=ABC)
(00002, address=1000+mity|mus=1|name=kailtig+bksyt|mas=1|mpc=4.977552|country=ABC)
```

While you convert it like this

```
A = load 'myData.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (ID, ATTRIBUTES);
B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(ATTRIBUTES, '\\|')) ;
C = foreach B generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));
```

Then, to my current understanding, if you take

```
DESCRIBE B;
```

It should return "Schema for B unknown."

Which is caused by the fact that at that point you have two rows with different number of columns. If you now look at C with describe it'll probably give {NULL}. Manual says that unknown schema is actually treated as bytearray but it seems that it can't be converted to chararray and

```
D = FOREACH C GENERATE (chararray)$0
```

gives "Cannot cast bytearray to chararray". Slightly different reaction follows from

```
D = FOREACH C GENERATE $0 as foo:chararray
```

which gives "ERROR 1031: Incompatable field schema: declared is "C:chararray", infered is ":NULL""

This is my understanding on what happened while I was attempting similar thing with my data, and pig 0.11.1. This doesn't really solve the problem though. I hope the only solution is not to store it to disc and read in in again.

Answer (score 0):

When you DESCRIBE B and it returns "Schema unknown" or any of column as NULL that means schema or data type is not defined.
It give issue since CAST of bytearray is having the issue.
Therefore Use STORE to create file and LOAD again with schema could resolve this issue.
Yes an overhead!